# Why a UserList subclass appears to return the wrong type for slicing?

Tags: python, collections, subclassing

Let me start by saying I get why subclassing `list` doesn't work as you might expect (because `list` is a primitive built-in type and there are issues of performance, etc.). AFAIK collections.UserList is supposed to avoid all these problems and make subclassing UserList work completely as you might expect. For example,

```
class DumbList(list):
  pass
d1 = DumbList([1,2,3])
d2 = DumbList([4,5])
type(d1 + d2)
```

returns `<class 'list'>`, but

```
from collections import UserList
class DumbList(UserList):
  pass
d1 = DumbList([1,2,3])
d2 = DumbList([4,5])
type(d1 + d2)
```

returns `<class '__main__.DumbList'>` as expected. However, slicing appears to return the wrong type, even when using `UserList` instead of `list`:

```
class DumbList(UserList):
  pass
d = DumbList([1,2,3])
type(d[:2])
```

returns `<class 'list'>`, not `<class '__main__.DumbList'>` as expected.

Two questions:

- Why is this?
- What should I do to make slicing return the correct type? The simplest thing I can think of is something like:

```
class DumbList(UserList):
  def __getitem__(self, item):
    result = UserList.__getitem__(self, item)
    try:
      return self.__class__(result)
    except TypeError:
      return result
```

...but it seems like this kind of boiler-plate code should be unnecessary.

Comment: Related: http://bugs.python.org/issue491398

Comment: Well done! You've just discovered why I always *discourage* from inheriting from built-ins! It just *looks* easier, but it's a nice way to introduce bugs in your code. Also note that, to create a proper subclass, not only you have to reimplement *every* method of the original class, but you even have to implement the `__r*__` variants to make it work properly in every situation! In other words using delegation is *always* less work. Use inheritanche only if you really care to have a subclass and not simply something that acts like a class (e.g. to "fool" `isinstance` checks)

Comment: BTW I'm using Python 3.4.2 for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, plain slicing (without a stride) would be handled by the [`__getslice__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__). The `UserList` implementation predates the addition of extended slices (with stride) to the language and never added support for them, see [issue 491398](http://bugs.python.org/issue491398).

The Python 3 implementation simply took the Python 2 version, moved into `collections` and removed `__getslice__` and `__setslice__` as those are no longer supported in Python 3.

As such, the `__getitem__` implementation is still simply:

```
def __getitem__(self, i): return self.data[i]
```

assuming that slicing would be handled elsewhere.

In Python 3, all slicing is handled by passing in the [`slice()` built-in type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) to `__getitem__`; simply test for that type and wrap the result in a `type(self)` call:

```
def __getitem__(self, i):
    res = self.data[i]
    return type(self)(res) if isinstance(i, slice) else res
```

Comment: So... it's basically a bug? =)

I do like your `type(self)(res)` better than my `self.__class__(res)`.

Comment: @KeenanPepper: well, you'll have to debate that with the Python devs. :-)